# How to remove this ?url= from get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, get

I have a error from link , when i click to submit a word

```
<form id="searchf" target="_blank" method="get" action="http://www.example.com/aa/bb/#/">
<input type="text" placeholder="free" name="url">
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

[image]

The Result :
http://www.example.com/aa/bb/?url=free#/

I want like this :
http://www.example.com/aa/bb/#/free/

Comment: You can't do that with a plain `<form>`. You will need JavaScript of some kind.

Comment: I'm a beginner learning JavaScript , thank you for this information

Comment: What kind of an error? What is the actual question here? Note also, that `#` and anything after it is not passed to your server.

Comment: @Teemu the “error” seems to be just “this is working differently than I had hoped it would” ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.replace` to redirect. Like:

```
$('#searchf').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace( $(this).attr('action') + $('[name="url"]').val() );
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#searchf').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace( $(this).attr('action') + $('[name="url"]').val() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchf" target="_blank" method="get" action="http://www.example.com/aa/bb/#/">
  <input type="text" placeholder="free" name="url">
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: @doctiroz Did you add the js code inside the `$('document').ready`?

Comment: No Sir , I try just this code `<script>
$('#searchf').submit(function(e) {
  window.location.replace($(this).attr('action') + $('[name="url"]').val());
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: If you are already using `jQuery`, you dont need to add the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: I updated the code. Please check. NO need to put inside the `$('document').ready`